# iOS displaying wrong text size

Tags: html, ios, css, mobile, mobile-safari

I have issues with text sizes on iOS Safari. All texts have the same size, but are displayed in different sizes on iOS, but not on desktop Chrome.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=1024" />
        <style>
            .content
            {
                width: 984px;
                margin: 0px auto;
            }
            .left
            {
                float: left;
                width: 165px;
                border-right: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
            }
            .page
            {
                margin: 0px 0px 80px 180px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="content">
            <div>
                <div class="left">
                    <div class="portrait">TEST TEST TEST</div>
                </div>
                <div class="page">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
                    incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis
                    nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
                    Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu
                    fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in
                    culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Unfortunately, this can't be shown in jsFiddle, so you have to save this as an html file and open it in Google Chrome. When using developer tools (F12) and going in device mode and changing the device width, the text gets bigger!

**Normal size**

[image: Normal size]

**Smaller device width**

You can see that the text on the right is bigger than on the left. This is what's causing my problems.

[image: Smaller device width]

How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your viewport is causing the issue, If you change it to the following, it will scale the font-sizes correctly.

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

Comment: Nope, still the same.

Comment: Have you tried giving it a specified font size? It doesn't look like there is any font-size assigned.

Comment: Yes, I tried that. This code here is just a minimalistic example of the website I'm trying to fix. I've seen this `-webkit-text-size-adjust` somewhere else and tried it before, but it's not working. Try it in Chrome and see.

Comment: Yes, this fixes it, but I want the device to "know" that 1024px is the correct width. My layout is 1024px fixed-width & centered. How do I correctly set up that?

Comment: But then the layout doesn't look good on desktop browsers because the content is centered and there is background stuff outside of the 1024px main content.

Comment: Sorry, you would want to put the entire thing in a wrapper. Something like: `#wrapper {width: 1024px; margin: auto;}`, similar to what to you did for `.content`.

Comment: It's the same thing. But that class isn't 1024px. So it won't be that wide.

Comment: That's because it also has padding, which I didn't put in the code above because it's just minimalistic proof of concept code.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking then. It also seems like a separate question. I believe the initial question was answered.

Comment: It wasn't, because `width=device-width` is not working for me. a width of 1024px is necessary for mobile devices to choose the correct width of the site. When using device-width, the mobile browser doesn't use the correct width.

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding, but it sounds like you want it to prevent scalling everything down? In that case, you probably need to duplicate the css and and wrap it in a media query.

Comment: After some fiddling, I came up with using both device-width and -webkit-text-size-adjust: none. Thanks for your support & help!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the meta tag is causing it. Is there a reason why you've set `<meta name="viewport" content="width=1024" />`, rather than `width=device-width`?

Comment: Yes. It's because I use a layout with a fixed width of 1024px which is also centered. This is so the mobile device "knows" what the preferred width is.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the font size for the specific div. also add the media query.

.content
            {
                width: 984px;
                margin: 0px auto;
                font-size:13px;

```
        }
        .left
        {
            float: left;
            width: 165px; font-size:15px;
            border-right: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
        }
        .page
        {
            margin: 0px 0px 80px 180px; font-size:13px;
        }
```